# wired color blocks when running a CLI program based on Python and prompt_toolkit in cmder

Tags: python, command-line-interface, cmder, prompt-toolkit

When running a Python CLI program based on prompt_toolkit in cmder, there are strange color blocks in the UI. It appears to be a problem with Chinese character parsing, as lines containing Chinese characters render with color blocks exceeding their expected length. However, this issue does not occur in PowerShell
looks fine in powershell:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylvWg.jpg)
wired in cmder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrIKe.jpg)

how to slove this problem to make the UI looks good